# Get index of selected text inside text input

Tags: javascript, html, text, dom-events

If you have an HTML `input` element, how can you detect the index of starting and ending positions of selected text inside that `input`? I tried using `window.getSelection` but it does not seem to work correctly. I would need to figure this out on the `keydown` event.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` property to get the indexes of the respective values.

```
var start = document.getElementById("myArea").selectionStart;  
var end = document.getElementById("myArea").selectionEnd;

console.log(start);
console.log(end);
```

Comment: Thanks! What's browser support for this?

Comment: It will work in modern browsers.  For older IE, you will need to do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/263743/573218